# In-place parsing using regular expressions in bash

Tags: awk, sed

I'd like to parse the strings in the 4th column and while removing unwanted characters rewrite the results in the same column.

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
Y   12914512    12914512    C/0.214286  A
Y   12914721    12914721    C/0.642857  T
Y   13355944    13355944    A/0.642857  G
Y   13414871    13414871    C/0.642857  T
Y   13470103    13470103    G/0.214286  A
Y   13479657    13479657    G/0.642857  C
Y   14824110    14824110    T/0.933333  *
Y   14824111    14824111    A/0.933333  *
Y   14840785    14840785    C/0.690476  T
Y   14840887    14840887    C/0.933333  T
Y   19705901    19705901    A/0.272727  G
Y   19731995    19731995    A/0.928571  C
Y   19735493    19735493    T/0.928571  C
Y   20587967    20587967    A/0.642857  C
Y   20756691    20756691    C/0.642857  T
Y   21904151    21904151    G/0.9375    A
```

I'd like to remove any trailing characters after the "/" in the fourth column and replace it with values in the fifth column so my modified text looks like this:

```
Y   12840422    12840422    G/A
Y   12914512    12914512    C/A
Y   12914721    12914721    C/T
Y   13355944    13355944    A/G
```

I have come up with the code below, but it doesn't produce what I expect:

```
awk -F ":" '{print $1"/"$2}' myTEXT.txt | sed 's/\([^/]*\)\{4\}$//'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
awk '{sub(/[^\/]*$/, "", $4); print $1,$2,$3,$4$5}' file > newfile
```

See the [`awk` demo online](https://ideone.com/8frlWV).

**Details**

- `sub(/[^\/]*$/, "", $4)` removes all chars other than `/` at the end of Field 4
- `print $1,$2,$3,$4$5` prints Field 1, 2, 3, and then concatenates what remained of Field 4 and Field 5.

Answer (score 3):

another (golfed) `awk`

```
$ awk '{k=$NF;sub("/.*","/"k)}1' file

Y   12914512    12914512    C/A
Y   12914721    12914721    C/T
Y   13355944    13355944    A/G
Y   13414871    13414871    C/T
Y   13470103    13470103    G/A
Y   13479657    13479657    G/C
Y   14824110    14824110    T/*
Y   14824111    14824111    A/*
Y   14840785    14840785    C/T
Y   14840887    14840887    C/T
Y   19705901    19705901    A/G
Y   19731995    19731995    A/C
Y   19735493    19735493    T/C
Y   20587967    20587967    A/C
Y   20756691    20756691    C/T
Y   21904151    21904151    G/A
```

might be easier with `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's /.*(.) /\1 ' file
```

Comment: That sed command uses spaces as the separator... that's almost evil obfuscation!

Comment: @BenjaminW. I agree. I would never use that. Well but as you said it's just _almost_ evil. Evil would be to omit the single quotes: `sed s\ /.*(.)\ /\1\  file` :)

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed for "inplace" editing and `\s` shorthand:

```
sed -i 's:/.*\s:/:' file
```

or with GNU awk for the same:

```
awk -i inplace '{sub(/\/.*\s/,"/")}1' file
```

In either case the input file becomes:

```
$ cat file
Y   12914512    12914512    C/A
Y   12914721    12914721    C/T
Y   13355944    13355944    A/G
Y   13414871    13414871    C/T
Y   13470103    13470103    G/A
Y   13479657    13479657    G/C
Y   14824110    14824110    T/*
Y   14824111    14824111    A/*
Y   14840785    14840785    C/T
Y   14840887    14840887    C/T
Y   19705901    19705901    A/G
Y   19731995    19731995    A/C
Y   19735493    19735493    T/C
Y   20587967    20587967    A/C
Y   20756691    20756691    C/T
Y   21904151    21904151    G/A
```